# Is it still a partial port or does it take a different approach?

Tags: 8, panels

At the moment of this question, I am using:

- Drupal 8.1.3
- Panels 8.x-3.0-beta4
- Page Manager 8.x-1.0-alpha23
- Layout plugin 8.x-1.0-alpha22

I am having difficulties replicating what was easy with Drupal 7, and I am not sure if the reason is simply that the ports of Panels and Page Manager are still incomplete, or that the approach has changed and I am not getting it.

**In Drupal 7**, you could create panels, and insert content into panes:
[image: Drupal 7, adding content to pane]

You could really add anything into a pane.

**In Drupal 8**, it looks like I can only add blocks:
[image]

What I want to achieve is being able to override a basic page (I'm overriding `/node/{node}`), and for example have a simple 1-column layout to display:

---

```
          <node title>
```

---

```
           <block 1>
```

---

```
          <node body>
```

---

```
           <block 2>
```

---

It could be more complex than that of course.

So, back to my question: is it just a matter of waiting for a complete port of Panels, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten to install one of the modules that implement panels.

From: drupal.org/project/panels

> Panels in Drupal 8
>
> We’re actively working on Panels for Drupal 8 which works with the new layout_plugin module and mainly is an interface to configure and store these layouts.
>
> **Panels is an API in Drupal 8**
>
> **In order to use panels, you must use an implementing module. Currently, [Page Manager](http://drupal.org/project/page_manager) and [Panelizer](http://drupal.org/project/panelizer) implement panels.**
>
> If you’re interested in following the Drupal 8 port in detail, follow [#2169319: [meta] Drupal 8 port of Panels](https://www.drupal.org/node/2169319) in the issue queue OR join us on IRC every Tuesday at 12 noon CDT (UCT-0500) in the #drupal-scotch channel for our weekly meetings.

Comment: Installing Panelizer does indeed add More items to the list.